# XML2Java Mapping - Dealing with Inheritance

Tags: java, xml, binding

I've encountered with a problem during my thesis and I hope someone out there can help me. The problem is the following, I'm working with a large source code ( an already made library) and want to do some xml binding to some classes through the specification of an input.xml file. Here is an example how a part of the code is structured:

```
interface IObject extends Writeable, PrimitiveSinkable{
   //methods, fields...
}
interface IMessage extends IObject{
//methods, fields....
}

interface IRequestMessage extends IMessage, IObject{
//methods, fields...
}

class RequestMessageVer10 implements IRequestMessage{
//methods, fields....
}

class RequestMessageVer11 implements IRequestMessage{
//methods, fields....
}
```

So, I what I want is by having an input.xml file to map from the interface IRequestMessage to the right class through the version attribute, here is an example of the pretended xml:

```
<requestmessage version=10>
//other fields...
</requestmessage>
<requestmessage version=11>
</requestmessage>
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how? Otherwhise, how can I circumvent it?

Best Regards,

Diogo Duarte﻿

Comment: Just being a bit pedantic but classes implement interfaces.

Comment: You are correct! Didn't saw the error, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly. I assume that you have the xml with the configuration and want to create instances of the classes declared there. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. I want to instantiate the classes corresponding to the specified version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already parsed the xml file and have a *version* variable with that information you can use the [Class.forName(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) like this:

```
IRequestMessage message = (IRequestMessage)Class.forName("RequestMessageVer"+version).newInstance();
```

If you need to pass parameters to the class constructor you can find a particular constructor and use it. Here is an example that finds the RequestMessageVer11 class constructor that takes a String and an Integer as parameters:

```
IRequestMessage message = (IRequestMessage)Class.forName("RequestMessageVer"+version).getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance("String parameter", 42);
```

If you need to parse the XML file I recommend a simple [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you missed the point. I haven't parsed the xml file. What I want is to parse and map to the corresponding classes.